# Creating a loop in R to name (save) files based on the name of the variable they're stored in

Tags: r, gis, raster

this is probably a basic question but I still need some help to figure out what I should do.
My code is very simple, there are a bunch of calculations to get raster files stored in variables :NDWI,NDWI, VSI, etc. each calculation is based on an satellite image which has a name with the date in it. I will find a way to extract the date and store it in a variable.

In essence, what I want is a part of my code that goes over all the files created  to save them as raster in a specific path of my laptop, under this format ( "variable name"_"date".tif. )

What I have for now :

```
Dossier <- "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/Raster/sentinel/L1C_T31UDR_A019210_20190225T105315/S2A_MSIL1C_20190225T105021_N0207_R051_T31UDR_20190225T125616.SAFE/GRANULE/L1C_T31UDR_A019210_20190225T105315/IMG_DATA"
library(raster)
list.files(Dossier)

Bande1 <- raster(list.files(pattern = "\\B01.jp2$"))
Bande2 <- raster(list.files(pattern = "\\B02.jp2$"))
Bande3 <- raster(list.files(pattern = "\\B03.jp2$"))
Bande4 <- raster(list.files(pattern = "\\B04.jp2$"))


NDVI <- (Bande8-Bande4)/(Bande8+Bande4)
NDWI <- (Bande8A-Bande11)/(Bande8A-Bande11)
NDDI <- (NDVI-NDWII)/(NDVI+NDWII)

writeRaster(NDWI, "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/résultats R/NDWI.tif", overwrite = T)
writeRaster(NDVI, "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/résultats R/NDVI", overwrite = T)
writeRaster(NDDI, "C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/résultats R/NDDI.tif", overwrite = T)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list with your objects and then use `Map` to loop over it:

```
rasterList <- list(NDVI = NDVI, NDWI = NDWI, NDDI = NDDI)
filenames<-sprintf("C:/Users/Perrin/Desktop/INRA/résultats R/%s_%s.tif", 
                    names(rasterList), format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d"))
Map(writeRaster, rasterList, filenames, MoreArgs = list(overwrite = TRUE))
```

Comment: What about the `"variable name"_"date".tif` part?

Comment: @patL I think now it covers both the variable name and the date.

Comment: @PerrinRemonté you can upvote and/or accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I think the comment I wrote yesterday to thank you didn't make it. Your answer worked for me !